# Looping and making new column python

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have this loop

```
Source= []
for row in df['Num_Col']:
    if row[0:6].isdigit()==True and row[6:8].isalpha()==True:
        Source.append('Num')
        df['Source'] = Source
```

What I want to achieve is when I loop through the specified column I want it to look at the first 6 positions if they are digits and if the last two digits are alpha then I want it to append it to my Source list and then I want to make a new col named:

```
df['Source'] = Source
```

which would be whatever met the requirements of my if statement. I keep getting this error though

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I am okay if the rest of the column in this new columns are Nan I just want it to make the column with the parameters specified by the if statement. I just don't understand why it doesn't do that already.

```
     Num_col   Country 
  1  123456HK  Georgia   
  2  273HH123  Georgia
  3  123456HK  Georgia
  4  273HH123  Georgia
  5  123456HK  Georgia
```

So when I run that loop what i want it to return is this

```
     Num_col   Country   Source
  1  123456HK  Georgia   Num
  2  273HH123  Georgia   
  3  123456HK  Georgia   Num
  4  273HH123  Georgia   
  5  123456HK  Georgia   Num
```

So basically just add a column called source and then add only the values that matched the if statement in the column with the name specified which was Num, which is specified after the if statement.

Comment: can you add an overview of your dataframe and your expected output ?

Comment: Yes I can, one second.

Comment: Using pandas right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested your code since I don't have the data, but it looks like you're trying to set source every single time. This doesn't make sense since the `Source` array (reserve capitals for classes btw), does not match the data frame column size.

As such, you should apply the new column at the end of your construction. Something like:

```
Source= []
for row in df['Num_Col']:
    if row[0:6].isdigit()==True and row[6:8].isalpha()==True:
        Source.append('Num')
    else:
        Source.append('')

df['Source'] = Source
```

even better! You can map!

```
def determine_num(row):
    if row[0:6].isdigit()==True and row[6:8].isalpha()==True:
        return 'Num'
    return ''

df['Source'] = df['Num_Col'].apply(determine_num)
```

full functions are a little more readable than lambdas

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to iterate over all rows of the `Num_col` column and apply a function. In this case, the function checks to see the condition you specified and returns different values depending on whether the condition is met or not.

```
import numpy as np # for the np.NaN value
df['Source'] = df['Num_col'].apply(lambda nc: 'Num' if nc[0:6].isdigit() and nc[6:8].isalpha() else np.NaN)

# Output:
   Country   Num_col Source
0  Georgia  123456HK    Num
1  Georgia  273HH123    NaN
2  Georgia  123456HK    Num
3  Georgia  273HH123    NaN
4  Georgia  123456HK    Num
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be axis=1 for row wise

Comment: @DylanMadisetti if I were operating on the whole dataframe the axis would matter. But because I'm only running `apply` on the subset `df['Num_col']` I don't think the axis matters

Comment: Ahh yeah snap. I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Better is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask created with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str), [`isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and [`isalpha`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isalpha.html):

```
mask = df['Num_col'].str[0:6].str.isdigit() & df['Num_col'].str[6:8].str.isalpha()
df['Source'] = np.where(mask, 'Num', '')
print (df)
    Num_col  Country Source
1  123456HK  Georgia    Num
2  273HH123  Georgia       
3  123456HK  Georgia    Num
4  273HH123  Georgia       
5  123456HK  Georgia    Num
```

For `nan`s:

```
df.loc[mask, 'Source'] = 'Num'
print (df)
    Num_col  Country Source
1  123456HK  Georgia    Num
2  273HH123  Georgia    NaN
3  123456HK  Georgia    Num
4  273HH123  Georgia    NaN
5  123456HK  Georgia    Num
```